# If I know the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, how can I find the distribution of $X - Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How can I find the distribution of $X - Y$If I know the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ from the individual distributions of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: You cannot. If you know something about the way they depend on each other you may be able find it but not in general.

Comment: Assuming $X,Y$ are independent, you could try to compute the characteristic function of MGF of $X-Y$ and see if it llooks like one you know.

Comment: As Kavi comments, you need to know the *joint distribution*.  The individual distributions will *only* give you this *when* they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $X,Y$ are independent, we can derive the following steps. Let $Z = X-Y$. Then, CDF of $Z$ can be expressed as
$$ F_Z(z) = \Pr \left\{ Z \leq z \right\}=\Pr \left\{ X - Y \leq z \right\}$$
Now, the tricky part is to send $Y$ to the other side of the inequality and take the average of expression for all possible $Y$ values weighting by their probabilities. In other words, you can apply this procedure with the help of integration.
$$F_Z(z) = \int_{<Y>}\Pr \underbrace{\left\{ X \leq z+y \right\}}_{F_X(y+z)}p_Y(y)dy $$
$$F_Z(z) = \int_{<Y>}{F_X(y+z)}p_Y(y)dy $$
Taking the derivative of both sides 
$$p_Z(z) = \int_{<Y>} p_X(y+z)p_Y(y)dy$$
is your answer. And as you see, the integral we derived is nothing but a convolution.